# MultipartFile has incorrect image data

Tags: spring-mvc, multipart

I am uploading an image file to a spring controller which has a MultipartFile argument. The image part looks like the following:

```
------=_Part_5_1153876276.1427135411345
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=frontImage
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="frontImage"; filename="frontImage"
```

The image size is 66348 bytes; however, when I copy the contents of the MultipartFile parameter, the size is 116612. I am not sure why this happens.

I am using CommonsMultipartResolver with a very basic configuration:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="4194304" />
</bean>
```

and I copy the contents of the parameter to the disk with the following code:

```
frontImage.transferTo(new java.io.File("/tmp/1.jpg"));
```

I have also tried copying the contents of frontImage.getInputStream() with the same result. The controller method has the following signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void save(@RequestParam("frontImage") MultipartFile frontImage,
                 @RequestParam("backImage") MultipartFile backImage) throws IOException {}
```

Comment: How can you tell the image is 66348 bytes long?

Comment: I have the image and I use soap ui to send the image and it tells me the parameter is 66348 bytes. Also the copied image to the disk is corrupted and does not open as an image.